# Adding nonclustered index to SQL Server table requires edmx file to update?

Tags: linq, edmx

In case we have added a nonclustered index to a SQL Server table, do we need to update the `.edmx` file?

Comment: Are you using EF migrations? If not then no. If you are you need to ensure the migration script(s) match the database schema.

Comment: No, we are not using EF migrations. We are using 'Update model from database' approach.